# how to avoid files to drop on the browser

Tags: jquery, file, drag-and-drop, browser

hi how to avoid the files to drop the files on the web browser.

I have been trying

```
 window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
                    e = e || event;
                    e.preventDefault();
                  },false);
```

but the above code is not working.

the files which i drop on the browser is still opening as download popup.

If you drag the file on the textbox it will show disable red icon and when you drop file in the text box it does nothing. Can we implement the same thing in the entire browser?

**UPDATED:**

working with this one line of code:

```
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are dropped outside the textbox, file is opened in the browser window. To avoid that we can prevent ‘drop’ event on document.

```
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) 
{
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('dragover', function (e) 
{
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 obj.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
});
$(document).on('drop', function (e) 
{
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

got my own answer which is working with one line of code...

```
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```